# CSS changes not updating

Tags: 8, theming, caching

Basic caching settings all off:

[image]

`settings.local.php` is loaded:

[image]

Bottom of settings.php:

```
if (file_exists($app_root . '/' . $site_path . '/settings.local.php')) {
   include $app_root . '/' . $site_path . '/settings.local.php';
}
```

And it contains:

```
$config['system.performance']['css']['preprocess'] = FALSE;
```

**Issue:** Add any changes to bootstrap subtheme at `themes/contrib/tekatheme/css/style.css` and save. Refresh page, no change. Has to run `drush cr` each time.

Running `drush cr` for each CSS edit is not a solution, it's impossible to work like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a Drupal caching issue. When CSS aggregation is disabled your browser loads the CSS files directly. So caching is between your browser and the web server. To disable caching you can either enable the dev mode in the browser or adjust the headers for CSS files in the web server.

By the way, `drush cr` doesn't clear CSS in cache. This wouldn't be possible because it is the browser cache. Instead it forces a reload by invalidating the cache-busting query string.

Comment: Correct answer. It was Nginx configs, `add_header` and `expires` rules for CSS and many other asset files.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting up `development.services.yml`?

Put this next to your `sites.php`.

**development.services.yml**:

```
# Local development services.
#
# Place this file in the /sites/ directory.
#
# To activate this feature, follow the instructions at the top of the
# 'example.settings.local.php' file, which sits next to this file.
services:
  cache.backend.null:
    class: Drupal\Core\Cache\NullBackendFactory
parameters:
  http.response.debug_cacheability_headers: true
  twig.config:
    # Twig debugging:
    #
    # When debugging is enabled:
    # - The markup of each Twig template is surrounded by HTML comments that
    #   contain theming information, such as template file name suggestions.
    # - Note that this debugging markup will cause automated tests that directly
    #   check rendered HTML to fail. When running automated tests, 'debug'
    #   should be set to FALSE.
    # - The dump() function can be used in Twig templates to output information
    #   about template variables.
    # - Twig templates are automatically recompiled whenever the source code
    #   changes (see auto_reload below).
    #
    # For more information about debugging Twig templates, see
    # https://www.drupal.org/node/1906392.
    #
    # Not recommended in production environments
    # @default false
    debug: true
    # Twig auto-reload:
    #
    # Automatically recompile Twig templates whenever the source code changes.
    # If you don't provide a value for auto_reload, it will be determined
    # based on the value of debug.
    #
    # Not recommended in production environments
    # @default null
    auto_reload: auto_reload
    # Twig cache:
    #
    # By default, Twig templates will be compiled and stored in the filesystem
    # to increase performance. Disabling the Twig cache will recompile the
    # templates from source each time they are used. In most cases the
    # auto_reload setting above should be enabled rather than disabling the
    # Twig cache.
    #
    # Not recommended in production environments
    # @default true
    cache: false
```

Then in your `settings.php`, or preferrably your `settings.local.php` add this line:

```
$settings['container_yamls'][] = DRUPAL_ROOT . '/sites/development.services.yml';
```